# Selecting the second column in a complex mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query for reporting purposes and I'm failing when i try to select the date (second column) from multiple joins (selects).

The query is something like this:

```
    SELECT a.Name, COALESCE(a.CustomerFaxes,0) AS 'CustomerFaxes', COALESCE(b.PoliceFaxes,0) AS 'PoliceFaxes', COALESCE(c.CustomerWebposts,0)AS 'CustomerWebposts', COALESCE(d.PoliceWebposts,0) AS 'PoliceWebposts', COALESCE(e.Letters,0) AS 'Letters'
FROM jobs j

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
    GROUP BY 1,2) a ON ...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
    GROUP BY 1,2) b ON ...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
    GROUP BY 1,2) c ON ...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
    GROUP BY 1,2) d ON ...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
    GROUP BY 1,2) e ON ..
JOIN table cu ON ...
JOIN table2 a ON ...
WHERE j.UserID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
AND j.receivedontime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP (20150302) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP (20150310)
GROUP BY 1;
```

This results in something like

User CustomerFaxes PoliceFaxes CustomerWebposts PoliceWebposts Letters

There are a lot of conditions in between. All sub queries have the second value as a date, i want to select it and group by it.
Any of you know a way?

Comment: What is failing?  How is it failing?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Well it works if i select a.time, b.time, c.time, and remove the group by 2. is there a way to group the column 2 from all the subqueries and select it as a single value?

Comment: you should use column names not indexes. and provide some data and expected result please. it would help a lot

Comment: I've added the whole query. I need to group also by date all the results.

Comment: Okay. Stop using the column numbers. Use the column names. Then just select `TableYouWantDateFrom.Date` - done.

Comment: I need the date from a, b, and c sub queries and group the whole result by it. As you can see from the result above, i already have the username and number of each case. I want to also add the received date from each subquery and group by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things

First, this is going to cause you a headache

```
 COALESCE(a.value2,0) AS 'value2', COALESCE(b.value2,0) AS 'value2'
```

You are trying to give two different columns in the same result set the same name.

Based on your comments, it sounds like what you really want is to get all date values in one column, using the date field from a first, then b, then c. You can do this by plugging them all into a single coalesce statement.

```
COALESCE(a.date,b.date,c.date) as Date
```

Second, you should probably know that column order is not particularly significant in SQL. You never select columns by column number. Naming your columns with an idex is confusing (what if someone reorders your query?) and doesn't help other users figure out what your query is trying to do. In the long run, readability matters more than anything else. You don't want to come back 6 months later and wonder what the heck your query was supposed to do.

Third, don't use date as a column name. Date is a resevered keyword in most implementations of SQL. Use a more informative name like 'DateRecieved' or 'DateOpened' or 'DateOfBirth' or 'TheDateTheEarthStoodStill'.

Comment: I'm so stupid, thanks this helped. COALESCE(a.date,b.date,c.date,d.date,e.date) works, and i've grouped by date

Answer (score 0):

Just use column names rather than numbers, and then select it from the relevant subquery - it's as simple as that.

For example -

```
SELECT c.Date AS Date
```

or

```
SELECT d.Date AS Date
```

whichever subquery you want the Date from, just use that.

Comment: j.ReceivedOnTime AS DATE is select for each query (a,b,c,d,e). My question is how do i get all results from all the queries in one column, so i can group by it.